# Robot Framework - can't find python module

Tags: python, robotframework

I decided to copy exactly the tutorial found [here](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/tree/master/doc/python) but somehow when i run it i keep getting the error

> "[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\path\to\tests': Importing test
>   library 'ExampleLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'ExampleLibrary' "

Now i tried both with the .py extension and without, just in case, but for some reason it doesn't work. Both files are in the same folder.

I have python 3 installed. I only copied the .tsv (renamed to a .robot) and .py files.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. If i work with only .robot files everything is fine.

Comment: You should describe exactly what you're doing in your question, including all the involved source code...not make readers try to construct what you're doing from an external link.

Comment: Can you show what's you do in detail more than this ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't fix problems in your code without seeing your code.

Comment: The link in the first line of the comment describes exactly what I am doing :)

Comment: Note that in case your Python file contains a class which contains a function that you wish to use as a keyword, then the name of the class MUST be the same as the name of the Python file you import as a library, i.e. -`Library  MyLibrary.py` within the `*** Settings ***` section of the `.robot` file while  the name of the class within the is ALSO exactly MyLibrary, i.e. - within the `MyLibrary.py` file: `class MyLibrary:....`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the relative path from the file .robot to the .py file:

```
Library ./ExampleLibrary.py
```

or the absolute. Or put the folder inside the PYTHONPATH env. variable and add the .py extension to the ExampleLibrary, because it is only a file and not a proper library (inside a folder).

Side note, the Python library file is incompatible with Python3 as it is now, and you have to make some minor corrections.

Answer (score 0):

After " Library " keyword there need to be two or more spaces or one or more tab. If you provided single characters of space between "Library" and your file, will get ModuleNotFoundError exception.